# When finding the derivative using its definition, why do we plug $0$ for $h$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, definition

If $\lim h\to 0$, when finding the derivative of the function, why do you plug in the limit that is being approached. Like why would you plug in $0$ in the function $4x+2h$ (which is the derivative of $\frac{2 (x+h)^2-2x^2}{h}$

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you improve it?

Comment: Okay so I did the rate of change formula for for the function 2x^2 in attempt to find the derivative.  My answer for this was as the Lim h-> 0 4x2h. So in my class,  I was told to plug in 0 for the h find the complete derivative. Why is that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 4x+2h

Comment: One doesn't "plug in" $0$, rather, one takes the limit as $h\to 0$. Your instructor was being sloppy. However, when a function is continuous (such as $f(h) = 2h$) then $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0)$.

Comment: Why do we do that? Can you explain a little more.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers are sufficient to tell you how to evaluate the limit, I think you're not sure why we take that limit as $h\to\color{blue}{0}$. So $\Delta x$ is your $h$. What you're looking for is intuition and nothing can give you better intuition than looking at this pic.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the answer above given by @wisher, note that the expression is simplified and the factor $h$ is divided out of numerator and denominator. Once that is done, what remains is a simple polynomial. In that case, you *really can* just plug in $h=0$ to get the limit.

Why? Because polynomials are continuous, so for a polynomial $p$, it is true that $$ \lim_{ h\to a} p(h) =p(a).$$

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I assume that you are trying to find the derivative of function $f(x)=2x^2$. So, as you suggest, we would like to look at the following limit
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2(x+h)^2-2x^2}{h}$$
Expending, we have
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2(x+h)^2-2x^2}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0}(4x+2h)=4x+\lim_{h\to 0} 2h=4x$$

Here, you are NOT taking $h=0$ but rather computing what is the value of $h$ as $h$ goes to 0.

Comment: Ohhh, okay ! I'm understanding a little better now, Thank you.